# Laravel 5.1 - Update name for current entry, must be unique to current User ID

Tags: php, validation, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I've got this code below in my `GeckoRequest` file. It works for the most part, however if I try to update an entry and keep the name as it is currently it fails saying that the name needs to be unique... Which it is as no other entries have this name apart from the *current* entry loaded in the edit form.

What is the best thing for me to do to check that the name is unique for the current user but also allow me to update the same entry without changing the name?

```
public function rules()
{
    switch($this->method())
    {
        case 'GET':
        case 'DELETE':
        {
            return [];
        }
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'morph' => 'required',
                'sex' => 'required',
                'genetics' => 'required',
                'name' => "required|unique:geckos,name,NULL,id,user_id," . \Auth::user()->id
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'morph' => 'required',
                'sex' => 'required',
                'genetics' => 'required',
                'name' => "required|unique:geckos,name,NULL,id,user_id," . \Auth::user()->id
            ];
        }
        default:break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of Null & id with Unique validation ?

I performed this thing by using it like this

` 'username'=> 'required|unique:users,username,'.$user->id `

Comment: It's been a long time since i worked on this project and I can't remember what it's for, but if I remove it it seemingly breaks the validation.

We're not checking a username is unique, we're checking a geckos name is unique in the current user's saved geckos. Currently even if i save the *same* gecko without changing the name it throws an error saying the name isn't unique

Comment: as per my R&D, the only way in which It gives error "name isn't unique " it can be because of logged-In user ID is not coming, So try dump Loggedin user-id and check that ID is coming or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able specify the id of the Gecko resource in the rule.

```
    case 'PATCH':
    {
        //This is assuming that you're using route model binding
        //and that it's called gecko and not geckos (or something else).

        $id = $this->route('gecko')->id; 

        return [
            'morph' => 'required',
            'sex' => 'required',
            'genetics' => 'required',
            'name' => "required|unique:geckos,name,{$id},id,user_id," . \Auth::user()->id
        ];
    }
```

This will tell laravel that it has to be unique unless the ids match.

**NB** When using the route method in a form validation class it will be looking for the additional params that have been passed through in the url (these are the parts of the url that are wrapped by `{}` in your routes file). Depending on how these have been set up and/or what version of `Laravel` you're using it is possible that Laravel will have resolved the param to a model.

If you are unsure how laravel is storing the param in the route, in the `rules()` method add `dd($this->route());`, submit the form and then the look at the response. The value will be in the `parameters` array.

If it is not being stored as a model and it's literally just the id: `$id = $this->route('gecko')`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Ross. I'll give this a go on my lunch break :)

Comment: If i've used a resource route that's geckos, I assume i just need to alter gecko to geckos? Would rather ask now than waste time later on haha

Comment: @AndyHolmes I've updated my answer to provide a little bit more information. Also, yeah just change `gecko` to `geckos` (or whatever you called the param in your routes file).

Comment: Thanks Ross, nice update too. Lunch in an hour so if all goes smoothly i'll accept then

Comment: Hey Ross, im using Route::resource('geckos', 'GeckoController');  FYI and $id = $this->route('geckos')->id; isn't bringing anything into the file so it's just firing back a non object error. Any ideas?

Comment: Just realised it's because i'm not passing the id through the form. Is there a way to grab the ID inside the request, i'd rather not have it in the form

Comment: If it's in the url it should be in the route. What does `dd($this->route());` give you?

Comment: I'm away from my laptop at the moment. I'm using the name in the form:model rather than the id. So if I was using the ID from the start, or if i include it in a hidden field it will work, but if you know of a way to access it inside the Request i'd appreciate it. If not i'll just put it as a hidden field, assuming it would be secure enough?

Comment: In my controller's edit method I do something like `$gecko_id = Gecko::find(compact('user_id', 'name'))->first()->id;` in order to find the id of the name of the gecko that belongs to the currently authenticated user. If i do the same in the update method, can i utilise that at all?

Comment: You could use something like that in your FormRequest class but it's not the cleanest. If you're using the gecko name as a slug you could always just changed the unique rule to `unique:geckos,name,{$name},name...`. You would get the name param using `$this->route('geckos')`.

Comment: Always trying to learn the clean ways, I didn't realise it worked like that so will just give that a go. So if the current name matches, it won't come up with the unique error?

Comment: It shouldn't do. Essentially the unique rules follows this convention: `unique:[table-name],[table-field],[whereNot-value],[whereNot-field],[where-field],[where-value]`. if you don't specify (or NULL) the [whereNot-field] it will assume the primaryKey of the table.

Comment: Gotcha, you've been very helpful, thank you so much :)

Comment: FYI using this code worked: `$name = $this->route('gecko');` and then `'name' => "required|unique:geckos,name,{$name},name,user_id," . \Auth::user()->id`